# Flutter show 3d images

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]I want to show 3d flutter image just like the [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ6KU.jpg). I am able to do 3d transformation and give effects like following attached image. What should be the best way to implement this kind of 3d effect? The Image I am using is 2D and I have applied 3d transformation, How can I give 3d effect? Which image should I use with 3d Perspective Transformation?

Comment: Check this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it use opengl plugin

this show url link : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_opengl

Comment: This is Android only and might not help the OP.